# package for coq odd order files missing in mathcomp?

Tags: coq, opam

I have coq installed via opam on Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to get (and ultimately run) the source code for the "stripped" proof of the odd order theorem; namely, the file `stripped_odd_order_theorem.v`. Here's more on my set-up:

```
$ coqtop -v
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl6 (June 2017)
compiled on Jun 14 2017 12:32:33 with OCaml 4.02.3
```

Commands like

```
opam install coq-mathcomp-solvable
```

work fine, but what I am looking for is the file `stripped_odd_order_theorem.v`, which I had in some early version of ssreflect when I had coq installed in another way. According to [coq.io](http://coq.io/opam/coq-mathcomp-odd-order.1.6.1.html) this file now seems to live in the package `coq-mathcomp-odd-order` but

```
$ opam install coq-mathcomp-odd-order
[ERROR] No package named coq-mathcomp-odd-order found.
```

I don't get it.

Comment: Try `opam update` before `opam install coq-mathcomp-odd-order`.

Comment: *hits head on desk* Many thanks.